# InjectionException when I restart module in weblogic server

Tags: java, dependency-injection, weblogic

I get some problem when i use weblogic. I deploy module, then I stoped this module and start again.

Result - InjectionException

I think after restart module ejb container destroy my beans.

```
    2018-03-09 09:41:40,343 ERROR U:n/a  ReqId:39e5a1b2-0936-4820-a72c-d80a6053fe4b ThrowableExceptionMapper toResponse - ERR: Internal server error, something went unexpectedly wrong.
javax.enterprise.inject.InjectionException: Exception trying to inject java EE injection point into class: com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.resource.impl.SnapshotResourceImpl.
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.ModuleContainerIntegrationService.performJavaEEInjection(ModuleContainerIntegrationService.java:405)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Dependency injection failure: can't find the bean definition about class interface com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService] is defined: No beans of type com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService; owner=com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968: display name [com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968]; startup date [Fri Mar 09 08:39:55 UTC 2018]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5fe15374; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl' is defined; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:218)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.ModuleContainerIntegrationService.performJavaEEInjection(ModuleContainerIntegrationService.java:398)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService] is defined: No beans of type com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.dataupload.hcp.service.UploaderTokenService; owner=com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968: display name [com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@2daab968]; startup date [Fri Mar 09 08:39:55 UTC 2018]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5fe15374; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl' is defined; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.getUniqueInstanceOfType(Jsr250Metadata.java:348)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:215)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl' is defined; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolve(Jsr250Metadata.java:265)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl in /app/webapp/api/uploader/v1/961601745.; remaining name 'comp/env/hcpUploaderTokenServiceImpl'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1224)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolve(Jsr250Metadata.java:258)
    ... 68 more
```

The problem is in a my code or maybe in weblogic?

Comment: Same here. Restarted the module, and the entityManagerFactory cannot be found in jndi and injection fails. Any updates on the issue?